# Blender animations and Unity

Tags: unity

I have created two Cubes and one bone which controls both objects (cubes). First cube is Red, second one is Blue. In first part of animation Red cube is rotating using bone and Blue cube is Hidden from outliner, in second part of animation Red cube is hidden and Blue cube rotates using same bone. Now when I save this as .blend or .fbx and import it to Unity game engine, and start animating both Cubes are Shown full animation and only rotation is animating. Why doesn't animate Hide on/off option from Blender outliner ?

Thx 
Ivan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't bother to do your animation work in Blender. Unity's animation tools are quite robust, and animating in Unity will make it easier to make different animations and behaviors for one model.

Blender behaviors like showing and hiding can't be translated accurately into Unity behaviors. So even if you had it working in Blender, you would have more work to do once you import it into Unity.

Just export what you have in Blender WITHOUT any animations and put it in Unity. Drop the model into your Unity scene, then open up the Animator. Click the dropdown under the record button and select [Create New Clip].

[image: Create a new animation clip]

To show and hide your cube, go to the appropriate frame of the animation, then enable/disable its Mesh Renderer. This will automatically add a keyframe to the animation clip. Do the rest of your animation as you would normally, adding rotation keyframes and such.

Answer (score 2):

For this basic animation and to show/hide cubes, you need to export the bone and cubes (both parented with armature ) to unity and do the animation in their.

Only your bone based animation and shapekeys are exportable to unity3d. Not other animations like moving one box location , rotaion or show/hide.