# Odd animation (without armature) when imported in Unity

Tags: animation, unity

i'm new to blender and i made a simple push animation([link to the blender project to have a look](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TovTwIWuC7dHZid0pZV2FrX28/view?usp=sharing)) for a button, in blender everything seems to work fine. 
When i export it as .FBX it works in unity, but not just out of the box, before i need too make some adjustment screened below.

After researching for a while on the net is not yet clear to me if this is just intended to work like this or i'm doing something wrong in blender.

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: same answer as in here i believe: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8722/blender-animations-and-unity