# How to get Unity3D to work with curve on tank track? (unapplied)

Tags: modifiers, rigging, bezier-curves, unity

I have this belt

[image]

and it rotates by translating the object on the y axis, but that doesn't work in Unity. In Unity, since the curve is unapplied, it translates instead? also it is below the ground as well.

Comment: i dont know, it accepts whatever you do in blender.

Comment: its not unity, its because my curve isnt applied. I guess i have to rig the belt, but i have no idea how...

Comment: This is not unity related. any engine will do this!

Comment: there i did that

Comment: Shape keys can simulate the movement.   Armatures can do the same.  We need a unity skilled person to make comments.  Otherwise I would search again and pose a new question.

Comment: answers.unity3d.com ?

Comment: Please see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8722/blender-animations-and-unity.   Inspect and Judge.  Some hope.   Shape keys and armature are valid animation techniques for Unity according to that discussion.  Please delete any unnecessary comments to attract more help to this topic.  Consider researching shape keys and armatures if necessary.